# Approximately evaluate the time needed for running an algorithm by CPU frequency

Tags: cpu-usage, evaluation

I just want to know, is that possible to evaluate approximately (to 1/6 hour) the time needed for executing an program ( an algorithm for example) , knowing the all the source codes and the frequency of the CPU of my computer ?

Comment: You mean, evaluate the time needed for executing a program *without* running it, right?

Answer (score 2):

No, because there's more to speed than CPU frequencies.

Answer (score -1):

You usually need the CPU frequency and a clock cycle counter or a high resolution timer. Most OS have one method or another (or even both)

Comment: You need at the very least the number of CPU, the RAM size and the bus speed.

Comment: We are talking of the time needed to execute a process in a coarse way... please read the question before downvoting. Or you can post here your full explanation. Intel uses these methods but I suppose you know more...

Comment: I think the OP wants the time needed to run a programm *without running it*. If running it is allowed, then yes, your answer is valid.

Comment: If that is the case, your answer is even more vague than mine... what about loops, for example?

Comment: @ManueldelCastillo , Actually, I do want to know the time needed to run a program without running it, yes, there maybe some loops, insert/get...or sth else, but as I said "Approximately"